# List Index is not returning values

Tags: regex, list, loops, email, outlook

I'm using Win32com in Python to access my Outlook emails, and I'm searching for a case number within the subject line of my emails, using regex.

For example, an email subject line may read Hisenburg CASE# 0039484. I have at least 30 emails like this.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd, os
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import win32com.client as client
import time, datetime, smtplib, imaplib, pathlib, re

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
account = namespace.Folders['name@company.com']
inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']
ap = inbox.Folders['Dean Brown']

pattern = re.compile(r'CASE# \d\d\d\d\d\d\d')
for x in message.items:
    b = re.findall(pattern, x.Subject)
    c = []
    for y in range(len(b)):
        c.append(b[y])
        print(c)
```

When I type **c** to get an item in the list, I get the following error:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

If I type **c[1]** I get the following error: **IndexError: list index out of range**

Why would I receive this error when my results (c) populates 30 Numbers?  Is there a way to populate the contents of email?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that you do not need to init `c` list in such a way, just assign the re.findall result to it.

Comment: And you might shorten it to `c = re.findall(r"CASE# \d{7}", x.Subject)`

Comment: I have made these edits as suggested in my original code.  However, any answers as to why my list index is out of range (i.e., c[1])?  c[0] only gives me the last Case# and ignores the other 14 cases.  How can I get all cases in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.  The contents from my email were not populating and I solved the problem using this code after the c.append(b[y]):

```
    for y in range(len(b)):
        c.append(b[y])
        with open('Case_File '+today+'.txt', 'a') as Case_File:
            Case_File.write('%s\n'%c)
```

This helped to send the appending values to a file which I was able to access and see all of my case numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `IndexError: list index out of range` because you are starting a loop:

```
for y in range(len(b)):
```

Then when you have added the first item to the array, you ask directly after it for the **second** item in the array using `c[1]` which does not exist yet.

```
c.append(b[y])
print(c[1])
```

If you want to get the first item, you can shorten the indenting one step to the left and use `c[0]` or `c[1]` depending on the available results in the list.

Note that you don't have to do the looping mechanism.

You can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) directly to return a list of strings.

```
c = re.findall(r"CASE# \d{7}", x.Subject)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately, this did not solve my problem.  For some reason, my contents from email don't appear to be present.

Comment: @belewis6i What do you see when you `print(x.Subject)`? You can see here that the pattern with re.findall yields the right result https://ideone.com/wmbuDR

Comment: @belewis6i Maybe there are 0 or more whitespace chars in between `CASE#\s*\d{7}`